# From my own website programmatically POST a video on my user's Facebook Wall

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I keep finding posts about preparing websites to be "postable" within the Facebook Status update (like with a youtube link that when typed from on the Facebook Status Update edit box and it will display in your TimeLine).

What I need is the opposite:
From my own website, I would like to have a button that when clicked, it should automatically post a specific video that is hosted within my website (or I could post a specific webpage that has the video inside).

What's the process to accomplish that?

Do I need Open Graph?
Do I need an Facebook App?
Do I need to use FQL?
Can I achieve this solely using FB Javascript SDK?
Should I use FacebookSDK for .Net (I'm using Asp.MVC and C#)?

Please any help would be truly appreciated.
I'm so lost on this one !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do I need Open Graph?***

> The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's
>   social graph. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that you can use to
>   query data, post new stories, upload photos and a variety of other
>   tasks that an app might need to do.

How to Use `Graph Api` Take a look at `FB Docs`. [The Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) and [Quick Start](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.0)

***Do I need an Facebook App?***

> You need to create `facebook app`. Its required for authentication
>   purpose. when you read and write its must need access. If you create
>   you will get `APP ID` and `APP Secret ID` to give the access.

Go [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/) and get logged in and Create an APP.

***Should I use FacebookSDK for .Net (I'm using Asp.MVC and C#)?***

> If you are okay to go with C# with ASP.NET then in `FaceBook Official site` they are suggesting many third parties SDK which is free. For
>   `Authentication, File Upload and Download` you can use the SDK.
>   ***[Click here to Go](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/other-sdks)***

***Can I achieve this solely using FB Javascript SDK?***

> I'm not sure whether you can use FB Javascript SDK for uploading. I
>   just guess you can't use. Take a look how they are using [***FB
>   Javascript SDK***](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0).

***Do I need to use FQL?***

> Facebook Query Language, or FQL, enables you to use a SQL-style
>   interface to query the data exposed by the Graph API. It provides
>   advanced features not available in the Graph API.

FQL Why and What? Read [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql)

Comment: This truly clarifies it. Thanks a lot.